# После переустановки openSevera не могу настроить xDebug

Tags: xdebug, php.ini

У меня был установлен ***OpenServer***. После его переустановки все выводы ошибок, `fatal error`, `Exception`-ов (даже перехваченных) и `var_dump`-ов.

Теперь исключения вовсе не выводятся, а если выводятся то без `stack trace`.
`var_dump` выводится весь в одну строку.

Я так понимаю все эти настройки в `php.ini`, помогите их настроить.

Answer (score 0):

В `php.ini` была закоментирована строка:

```
zend_extension="%sprogdir%/modules/php/%phpdriver%/ext/php_xdebug.dll"
```

Зачем без понятия.